# How to fetch data from multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Hello ever one i want to fetch individual values from a multidimensional array. so far i have done this

```
print_r($result);
```

and have the output like this

```
Array (
   [All Nodes Are Shuddha] => stdClass Object (
      [answer] => All Nodes Are Shuddha
   )
)
```

Kindly tell me how to have only the "Äll Nodes are shudhha"

Comment: don't you have 2 leves with that same value, which one do you want, the inner one ? or the outer one ?

Comment: yes i have tried using foreach as well but it says stdclass object error..and i want outer array value

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

```
echo $result['All Nodes Are Shuddha']->answer;
```

Comment: Yea I was going to say the same, till I noticed it's mentioned twice

Comment: Undefined index: All Nodes Are Shuddha

Comment: @AnkushSeth Your print_r($result); says that there is "All Nodes Are Shuddha". Maybe first letter "Ä" is different.

Answer (score 0):

Please use it as following by converting object to array.

```
$arr = (array) $result['Äll Nodes are shudhha'];
print_R($arr['answer']);
```

Comment: Undefined index: All Nodes Are Shuddha

Comment: @AnkushSeth Please replace "All Nodes Are Shuddha" with printed in your output. I think there may be some special character in key. Please check my update.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($result as $key => $values) {
   echo $key; // this should get the key 'All Nodes Are Shuddha'
}
```